# Flex-shrink in IE10

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-10

I have a block, in which there are an image and another block.

The parent block has `display:flex`, to make the image and the child block stand in a row.

The child block also has `display:flex`, but it forms a column made of paragraphs and heading.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNmYRq

```
.summary__testimonial{
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.summary__testimonial-right{
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction:column;
    flex-direction:column;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    -ms-flex-negative:1;
    flex-shrink:1;
    -ms-flex-pack:center;
    justify-content:center;
    width: auto;
}
```

The problem is that the text paragraph overflows his parents in IE 10.

I tried setting `max-width:100%`, `width:auto`, `box-sizing:border-box`, changing `flex-shrink` values to `1` and `0`.

It still either overflows, or becomes a single line, what you most probably see in the codepen, if you open it in IE 10.

Is there any way to make it look in IE 10 the same as in normal browsers?

Answer (score 3):

The IE10 equivalent of `flex-shrink` is `-ms-flex-negative`

For example,

```
-ms-flex-negative: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 10 is built using an [*older version of flexbox (2012)*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/).

This version doesn't provide `flex-shrink`. The property didn't exist at the time.

See the [Flexbox IE10 Property Index](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/#property).

The closest you can get would be the `-ms-flex` property, which sets "negative flexibility" ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh673531(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Comment: What is then this "-ms-flex-negative:1"? It was set by autoprefixer, is it useless?

Comment: I've never heard of it. More importantly, it's not in the MS Flexbox / IE10 guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh673531(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ok, but how to understand this: "If you have to support IE 10, the best solution is to always set an explicit flex-shrink value on all of your flex items, or to always use the longhand form". What do they mean, saying "explicit flex-shrink value", when IE10 doesn't have any flex-shrink value?https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs

Comment: User the `flex` / `-ms-flex` shorthand. It's in my answer, with a link reference.

Comment: Well, I tried to set -ms-flex: 0 0 auto for image and -ms-flex 0 1 auto for column, meaning that image shouldn't shrink, and column should. Nothing changed.

Comment: Well, I found out that if you set flex-shrink:1 (with this "-ms-flex-negative" prefix to make it work in ie10) and then set width:100% to .summary__testimonial-right, it seems to be working as expected.